Showing same post with 2 different URL
I have a website in WordPress version (6.5.4) and face a URL related issue.
For example, I have post URL like https://www.example.com/testabc, but when I enter this type of URL https://www.example.com/testabc/page/3/, it shows the same preview instead of 404 or redirect to actual URL.

I have set WordPress default .htaccess but it does not work
Set permalink /%postname%/
also checked with one by one plugin disable


I was facing like similar issue. Here's something you can try:
can you find in function.php something like template_redirect or redirect_canonical remove these things or comment and check it may work.
